# Why should I have the wrong voltage value when I use another way to calculate it?

Tags: voltage

The question wants to know \$V_{XY}=V_{X}-V_{Y}=X-Y\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP4Jxw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The solution said \$I=\frac{10}{15\text{k}\Omega+10\text{k}\Omega+5\text{k}\Omega+20\text{k}\Omega}=0.2\text{mA}\$,and \$V_{XY}=V_{X}-V_{Y}=(-0.2\text{mA} \times 20\text{k}\Omega)-(0.2\text{mA} \times 15\text{k}\Omega)=-7\text{V}\$,I understand its solution,but I have other thinking,and U think it should be right, but the answers are different.

My thinking:

\$I1=I2\$,that is,\$\frac{10-Y}{10\text{k}\Omega}=\frac{Y-0}{15\text{k}\Omega}\$,and we can know \$Y=6\$

\$I3=I4\$,that is,\$\frac{0-X}{20\text{k}\Omega}=\frac{X-(-10)}{5\text{k}\Omega}\$,and we can know \$X=-8\$

so \$V_{XY}=V_{X}-V_{Y}=X-Y=-8-6=-14\text{V}\$

Does anyone know where am I wrong?My answer is -14V,but the answer from the book is -7V.

Comment: As a basic sanity check : your answer has greater magnitude than the sum of all voltage sources in the circuit.

Comment: How can Vx be mathematically replaced with X. It doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @Andyaka Actually,i want to write \$V_X\$,but i can't not write it in the simulation figure.and yes ! you are right,i can just write VX instead of X,but i don't like it,so i just write X ,and X means \$V_X\$,LOL

Comment: The ground symbol is just there to fool you (as far as this problem is concerned anyway). Ignore it - or even better, choose your own ground point (I would choose the negative side of the voltage source). Just remember that the 2 points which were 'grounded' must be connected together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you know that \$I=I_1=I_2=I_3=I_4=200\:\mu\text{A}\$ as this is a series circuit and the currents must all be the same. (I'm agreeing with your computation of the series current magnitude and its sign as it relates to the direction shown in your schematic.)

But let's modify your schematic slightly:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0LTvj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All I've done is added two new node labels because I want to draw your attention to the idea that the voltages at \$A\$ and \$B\$ might not be what you assume they are. (In fact, I think you are assuming incorrect things about them.)

You wanted to compute the voltage at \$Y\$. This will be \$V_Y=I_1\cdot R_1=+3\:\text{V}\$. That's not the value you came up with. The reason is that one end of \$R_1\$ is grounded and the other end is then referenced to that ground and *only* \$R_1\$ is needed, together with the current through it, to work out the voltage at node \$Y\$. So you are already wrong here.

To compute the voltage at \$X\$ all you have to do is note that, for similar reasons, \$V_X=-I_4\cdot R_4=-4\:\text{V}\$. Again, one end of \$R_4\$ is grounded. So again, the voltage at node \$X\$ is entirely determined by the current through \$R_4\$ and the value of \$R_4\$. In this case, because of the arrow direction, the sign is opposite. But that's all.

So \$V_X-V_Y=-4\:\text{V}-3\:\text{V}=-7\:\text{V}\$.

Your thought was that the current through \$R_2\$ is \$I_2=\frac{10\:\text{V}-V_Y}{R_2}\$. But that's not true. It's actually \$I_2=\frac{V_A-V_Y}{R_2}\$. Do you see the difference? You assumed a value for \$V_A\$ which is ***not true***. This is why I wanted to add the two labels to your schematic. To highlight the fact that you made an assumption that was false.

A voltage source doesn't determine absolute values at locations. So, the fact that the difference in voltage between \$V_B\$ and \$V_A\$ is \$10\:\text{V}\$ in no way at all means that the voltage at \$V_A\$ is \$10\:\text{V}\$ or that the voltage at \$V_B\$ is \$0\:\text{V}\$. This, I think, is your error.

Answer (score 5):

The positive terminal of the source isn't at 10 V relative to ground, it's at 10 V relative to the negative terminal of the source.

Answer (score 1):

If you take the usual reference direction (right to left), you have 
\$V_Y + V_{R_2}-10 + V_{R_3} = V_X\$, or
\$V_X-V_Y = V_{R_2}-10 +V_{R_3}\$.

You have \$V_{R_2} = (0.2)(10) = 2\$ and \$V_{R_3} = (0.2)(5) = 1\$, hence \$V_X-V_Y = -7\$.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage source is 10V but when you probe it across the positive terminal and ground you will not measure 10 V. So, the second way of solving is wrong. The currents are equal but the equations are wrong due to the 10 V confusion.

Comment: You may or may not be correct, but your explanation is very confusing, and I'm not willing to try to figure it out.